# Can you nest a Spark Dataframe in another Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In spark I want to be able to parallelise over multiple dataframes.

The method I am trying is to nest dataframes in a parent dataframe but I am not sure the syntax or if it is possible.

For example I have the following 2 dataframes:
df1:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------------+------+
|id         |asset_id |                date|  text|
+-----------+---------+--------------------+------+
|20160629025|       A1|2016-06-30 11:41:...|aaa...|
|20160423007|       A1|2016-04-23 19:40:...|bbb...|
|20160312012|       A2|2016-03-12 19:41:...|ccc...|
|20160617006|       A2|2016-06-17 10:36:...|ddd...|
|20160624001|       A2|2016-06-24 04:39:...|eee...|
```

df2:

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------+
|asset_id|      best_date_time|  Other_fields|
+--------+--------------------+--------------+
|      A1|2016-09-28 11:33:...|           abc|
|      A1|2016-06-24 00:00:...|           edf|
|      A1|2016-08-12 00:00:...|           hij|
|      A2|2016-07-01 00:00:...|           klm|
|      A2|2016-07-10 00:00:...|           nop|
```

So i want to combine these to produce something like this.

```
+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
|asset_id|                 df1|                df2|
+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
|      A1| [df1 - rows for A1]|[df2 - rows for A1]|
|      A2| [df1 - rows for A2]|[df2 - rows for A2]|
```

Note, I don't want to join or union them as that would be very sparse (I actually have about 30 dataframes and thousands of assets each with thousands of rows).

I then plan to do a groupByKey on this so that I get something like this that I can call a function on:

```
[('A1', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x2534310>), ('A2', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x25d2310>)]
```

I'm new to spark so any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** It is not possible to nest `DataFrames` but you can use complex types.

In this case you could for example (Spark 2.0 or later):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct

df1_grouped = (df1
    .groupBy("asset_id")
    .agg(collect_list(struct("id", "date", "text"))))

df2_grouped = (df2
    .groupBy("asset_id")
    .agg(collect_list(struct("best_date_time", "Other_fields"))))

df1_grouped.join(df2_grouped, ["asset_id"], "fullouter")
```

but you have to be aware that:

- It is quite expensive.
- It has limited applications. In general nested structures are cumbersome to use and require complex and expensive (especially in PySpark) UDFs.